# Cost of buffer *sequence* allocation in boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Asio allows us to use custom allocators for handlers, there is even `bind_allocator()` helper function in recent versions of asio.

On the other hand, low level functions, like
`basic_stream_socket::async_read_some()` always deal with buffer sequences which [unlike a single buffer] also must be stored in memory allocated dynamically by the library. However, it seems that [please correct me if I'm wrong] there is no way to tune memory allocations for buffer sequences.

So here is my question: Why should we care about custom allocators for handlers and at the same time ignore a similar issue for buffer sequences?

Comment: "Why should we care about custom allocators for handlers" - you usually don't. This only comes in when you optimize for a lot of repeated async operations in repeat patterns that can benefit from some form of re-use.

Answer (score 1):

> So here is my question: Why should we care about custom allocators for handlers and at the same time ignore a similar issue for buffer sequences?

Because it will be exceedingly rare for the cost of the sequence to be significant.

E.g. if you're using

```
  std::vector seq {
       boost::asio::buffer(m_header),           
       boost::asio::buffer(m_data),
  };
```

And you don't like the vector overhead, you'll replace with another container:

```
  std::array seq {
       boost::asio::buffer(m_header),           
       boost::asio::buffer(m_data),
  };
```

This makes the entire sequence a simple POD value that the compiler can optimize for.

(Or if the size **is** variable some kind of static/SSO enabled container like [`static_vector` or `small_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html)).

Finally, a [`BufferSequence` is a concept](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MutableBufferSequence.html), so you can create your own model (e.g. using a smart-pointer or even a non-owning reference) that hits the exact performance spot you need.

Summarizing, the API doesn't impose any overhead, instead focusing on simplicity through genericity. (For me, undestanding this goes back to Dave Abraham's seminal piece "Want Speed? Pass By Value" after introduction of c++11 move semantics).

Comment: OK, but even if I use `std::array`, asio still must store the copy of the sequence in dynamic memory, right? Handler is also a concept, and yet we can select the allocation strategy.  So I'm trying to understand the difference here, (or to learn what I'm missing here). BTW, thanks for answering, I learnt a lot on asio from your posts here!

Comment: I think my answer already contains all the ingredients (you can choose your buffer model as well as the handler allocator). Keep in mind that implementation details maybe at play (e.g. `io_uring` represents buffers with an integral identifier internally)